# Error "desconocido" en formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login

Tengo un `php` que esta conectado a una `BD Mysql` y que su función es un **login**, el problema es que siempre me muestra que el *usuario o password* son incorrectos aun no siendo.

**Les dejo el PHP**

```
   <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "u268055042_audit";
$pass_db = "auditorioandroid";
$db_name = "u268055042_audit";
$tbl_name = "tbl_login";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion fallÃ³: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$username'";

$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     
 }
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>"; 

 } else { 
   echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";

   echo "<br><a href='login2.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion); 
 ?>
```

**Tabla tbl_login**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que datos estas introduciendo y que datos tienes almacenados?

Comment: @lois6b añadire la tabla a que esta conectado un momento

Comment: Ok, perfecto, gracias

Comment: No se si te has dado cuenta pero el segundo if lo abres y lo cierras seguidamente.

Comment: @lois6b añadido.

Comment: @Lithorell no lo habia notado ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verifica si tu consulta imprime algun dato, si te retorna alguno, el resto del codigo guardalo dentro de tu segundo if, osea dentro de este

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
// aqui va el resto del codigo para que se cumpla la condicion 
 }
```

a manera que tu codigo general pueda verse algo asi....

```
<?php
session_start();

$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "u268055042_audit";
$pass_db = "auditorioandroid";
$db_name = "u268055042_audit";
$tbl_name = "tbl_login";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion fallÃ³: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}else{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$username'";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

        echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
        echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>"; 

     } else { 
       echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";

       echo "<br><a href='login2.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
     }
mysqli_close($conexion); 
 }
 ?>
```

verifica eso amigo, espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Gracias por la idea !

Answer (score 0):

Por que mejor no validas el password directamente en query? y así te evitas la doble validación con PHP.

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $host_db = "localhost";
    $user_db = "u268055042_audit";
    $pass_db = "auditorioandroid";
    $db_name = "u268055042_audit";
    $tbl_name = "tbl_login";

    $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

    if ($conexion->connect_error) {
     die("La conexion fallÃ³: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

    $result = $conexion->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

        echo "Bienvenido! " . $username;
        echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>";

     }
     else { 
       echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";

       echo "<br><a href='login2.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
     }
     mysqli_close($conexion); 
     ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la idea !